# Removing dynamically added controls with javascript (In asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form where a person fills in expenses, and the added controls come in pairs of a textbox and checkbox(fx. expense1 and mastercard1). I want to be able to remove one of these "expenses" if they add one too many.

```
var tbId = 'expense';
var chkId = 'Mastercard';
var tbCounter = 0;

$("#txt").click(function () {

    if(tbCounter > 10){
        alert("Der kan ikke tilføjes flere udgifter");
        return false;
    }   

    var br = document.createElement("br");
    var ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name: 'text', value: 'Indskriv udgift', id: tbId + (++tbCounter)}).addClass("form-control tb_Id");
    var ctrl2 = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'checkbox', name: 'chk', id: chkId + (tbCounter) }).addClass("chk chk_Id");

    $("#ExpenseBoxes").append(br, ctrl, 'Mastercard: ', ctrl2, br);
});

$("#removeBtn").click(function () {
    if(tbCounter == 0){
        alert("Der er ikke mere at fjerne");
        return false;
    }

    $("#ExpenseBoxes").find(tbId + tbCounter).remove();
    tbCounter--;
});
```

This is where the controls are inserted:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   <input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox"/>
   <input type="button" id="removeBtn" value="Slet udgift" />
   <div id="ExpenseBoxes">
   </div>
</div>
```

I thought something like this "removeBtn" function would work, but it doesn't and i was wondering if i was completely off or if there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: Please explain "doesn't". What do you expect to happen that doesn't? Also, check your console for errors.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear about that, what I meant by "doesn't work" is that nothing happens, the console doesn't report any errors either

Answer (score 0):

I made a similar form last week, but i was using Table/rows instead of div also mine was in JS instead of jquery. The whole idea was to delete the rows within a table. So it would be something like this

In this case, there would be only 1 row to delete. I hope this helps

**JS**

```
function deleteRow(){ 
      document.getElementById(ptTable).deleteRow(0);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="ptTable">
  <tr>
    <td>< input type="button" id="txt" value="Add TextBox"/></td>
    <td>< input type="button" id="removeBtn" value="Slet udgift" /></td>
    <td>< button onClick="deleteRow();return false;"/> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, all my tables have their unique index, for the sake of keeping track.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that the click event associated with the id does not work at first when i tried the same.
Later i realise that scripts which are bonded with html elements should be placed at the end of HTML code.

I placed the script below my html and it started working.

> The reason behind this is when javascript getting loaded before html, it
>   does not find DOM elements referenced in javascript, as that is not
>   loaded yet.

Please try the same, if that is the same issue you are facing.